# Disable automatic zoom in on the data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a scatter plot with the x axis being the day of the year.
I always want the whole X axis shown, even when I hide dataset A (by clicking on the blue box).
For the Y axis it already works

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("plot").getContext('2d');

var doyChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        labels: ['2016-01-01', '2016-11-01', '2016-12-01'],
        datasets: [{ label: 'A', backgroundColor: 'blue',
                     data: [{t: '2016-07-08', y: 1},{t: '2016-12-29', y: 1}]
                     },
                   { label: 'B', backgroundColor: 'red',
                     data: [{t: '2016-11-01', y: 2}] 
                     }
                    ]
    },
    options: {
       scales: {
          xAxes: [{ type: 'time', 
                    ticks: { source: 'labels',  
            /*min: moment("2016-01-01"), max: moment("2016-12-31") */
            min: "2016-01-01", max: "2016-12-31" 
                           },
                time: {parser: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                   displayFormats: {day: 'MMM D' },
                           stacked: true
                    }
          }],
          yAxes: [{ ticks: {
                       beginAtZero:true,
                       max: 2,
                },
          }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="plot" ></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>


 </body>
</html>
```

My `min` and `max` values seem to have no effect at all, I tried as date and as string, to no avail.

Comment: this is working fine, Have a look

Comment: @DupinderSingh Oh sorry, I had a typo in the problem description. I want to hide the blue dataset A without zooming in on the red dot.